# How do I iterate through an object containing 2D arrays without getting O(n)^3?

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, big-o, nested-loops

Hopefully this is not too specific of a question, but I'm hoping to get insight into how to work with nested Objects and Arrays without making a program that runs O(n)^2 or O(n)^3.

Below is a program I built to find the cheapest flight(s) from point A to point B, and if the flight is the same price, the one with the least amount of flights. You will see where I label the parts that are not efficient. How can I make these more efficient?

```js
//returns an object with an array of IDs that will get you to a destination at the lowest cost. if same cost, then the least amount of flights flights

function leastExpensiveFlight(flightInfo, start, end) {
  var numOfTimes = 1
  var combinedValues = []
  var minValue
  var indexOfMinValue;
  var numOfFlights = []
  var minNumberOfFlights;
  var startTimes = flightInfo.reduce((startTimes, f, index) => {
    if (f[0] == start) {
      startTimes[numOfTimes] = [f];
      numOfTimes++
    }
    return startTimes
  }, {})
  //below is O(n)^2  
  //Gets the Flights where Location 1 = start 
  for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(startTimes).length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < startTimes[Object.keys(startTimes)[i]].length; j++) {
      flightInfo.forEach((f, ) => {
        if (startTimes[Object.keys(startTimes)[i]][j] &&
          f[0] === startTimes[Object.keys(startTimes)[i]][j][1] &&
          startTimes[Object.keys(startTimes)[i]][j][1] <= end &&
          f[1] <= end) {
          if (!startTimes[Object.keys(startTimes)[i]].includes(f)) {
            startTimes[Object.keys(startTimes)[i]].push(f)
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
  //below is O(n)^3!!
  //Finds trips that will get to the destination
  Object.keys(startTimes).forEach((flights) => {
    startTimes[flights].forEach((subFlights1, sFIndex1) => {
      startTimes[flights].forEach((subFlights2, sFIndex2) => {
        if (subFlights1[0] === subFlights2[0] &&
          subFlights1[1] === subFlights2[1] &&
          sFIndex1 != sFIndex2) {
          if (subFlights1[2] >= subFlights2[2]) {
            startTimes[flights].splice(sFIndex1, 1)
          } else {
            startTimes[flights].splice(sFIndex2, 1)
          }
        }
      })
    })
  })
  //below is O(n)^2  
  //Finds the trip with the minimum value and, if same price, least amount of flights
  Object.keys(startTimes).forEach((flights, sTIndex) => {
    startTimes[flights].forEach((subFlights, sFIndex) => {
      if (sFIndex == 0) {
        combinedValues[sTIndex] = subFlights[2]
        numOfFlights.push(1)
      } else {
        combinedValues[sTIndex] += subFlights[2]
        numOfFlights[sTIndex] += 1
      }
      if (sFIndex === startTimes[flights].length - 1 &&
        ((combinedValues[sTIndex] <= minValue) ||
          !minValue)) {
        if ((!minNumberOfFlights ||
            minNumberOfFlights > numOfFlights[sTIndex])) {
          minNumberOfFlights = numOfFlights[sTIndex]
        }
        if (combinedValues[sTIndex] === minValue &&
          numOfFlights[sTIndex] === minNumberOfFlights ||
          (combinedValues[sTIndex] < minValue &&
            numOfFlights[sTIndex] >= minNumberOfFlights) ||
          !minValue) {
          minValue = combinedValues[sTIndex];
          indexOfMinValue = sTIndex
        }
      }
    })
  })

  return startTimes[Object.keys(startTimes)[indexOfMinValue]]
} //Big O is O(n)^3

//2D Array: data[0][0] = Location start,
//          data[0][1] = Location end,
//          data[0][2] = Price,
//          
var data = [
  [4, 5, 400],
  [1, 2, 500],
  [2, 3, 300],
  [1, 3, 900],
  [2, 3, 100],
  [3, 4, 400]
]

//so from location 1 - location 3, the cheapest route would be: [1,2,500],[2,3,100]
console.log(JSON.stringify(leastExpensiveFlight(data, 1, 3)));
```

Your help is much appreciated. I am trying to get better at coding so I can go into my engineering department, but as you can see, I have a long way to go.

[EDIT]- Sorry, had an erroneous statement in there that I just fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd approach this by first constructing a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) for each possible path between the start and end nodes. Make a function that, given a start node and a list of nodes already visited, can look through the data to find each path leading out of this node. For each path which has *not* been visited yet, if the path ends at the destination, push the whole result of the paths traveled to a `finishedPaths` array. Otherwise, recursively call the function so that it does the same process again, starting at the end node.

To reduce complexity, to identify whether a node has or hasn't been visited yet, use an object or Set (which have lookups in `O(1)` time, unlike `Array.prototype.includes`, which runs in `O(n)` time).

At the end, look through all the possible paths between the start and end, identify the ones with the lowest cost, and among those, find the one with the least number of paths.

```js
function leastExpensiveFlight(data, start, end) {
  const pathsByStartLoc = {};
  for (const path of data) {
    const start = path[0];
    if (!pathsByStartLoc[start]) pathsByStartLoc[start] = [];
    pathsByStartLoc[start].push(path);
  }
  const getAllPaths = (
    start,
    costSoFar = 0,
    pathsSoFar = [],
    finishedPaths = [],
    visitedNodes = {}
  ) => {
    if (!pathsByStartLoc[start]) return;
    for (const path of pathsByStartLoc[start]) {
      if (visitedNodes.hasOwnProperty(path[2])) continue;
      if (path[1] === end) {
        finishedPaths.push({ totalCost: costSoFar + path[2], paths: [...pathsSoFar, path] });
      }
      getAllPaths(
        path[1],
        costSoFar + path[2],
        [...pathsSoFar, path],
        finishedPaths, { ...visitedNodes, [path[0]]: true }
      );
    }
    return finishedPaths;
  };
  const allPaths = getAllPaths(start);
  const lowestCost = Math.min(...allPaths.map(({ totalCost }) => totalCost));
  const lowestCostPaths = allPaths.filter(({ totalCost }) => totalCost === lowestCost);
  return lowestCostPaths.reduce((a, item) => a.paths.length < item.paths.length ? a : item);
}       
var data = [
  [4, 5, 400],
  [1, 2, 500],
  [2, 3, 300],
  [1, 3, 900],
  [2, 3, 100],
  [3, 4, 400]
]

//so from location 1 - location 3, the cheapest route would be: [1,2,500],[2,3,300]
console.log(leastExpensiveFlight(data, 1, 3));
```